# Batch script rename file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a file called xxxxxxx_12345.pdf and I try to delete the suffix and the result would be xxxxxxx.pdf. 
I tried following:

```
forfiles /S /M *_12545.pdf /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname*.pdf"
```

but it could not change the file name.
Can somone help to solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: If you really have **a file**, then there would be no need for forfiles at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a way to do the job with `forfiles` command, however, it would be much easier to use regular `for` loop for this.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*_12545.pdf) do (
    set "CurrentFileName=%%~nf"
    set "RenameTo=!CurrentFileName:~0,-6!"
    echo.ren !CurrentFileName!%%~xf !RenameTo!%%~xf
)

pause>nul
```

By `setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, user can use delayed environment variables, which will enable user to use something like `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.

```
set "CurrentFileName=%%~nf"
```

`%%~nf` will give you the name of the file without extension, so in this case, `CurrentFileName` will be `FileName_12545`. Type `for /?` to see the full explanation of the syntax.

```
set "RenameTo=!CurrentFileName:~0,-6!"
```

Notice that I used `!variable:~0,-6!` to remove suffix. This is [String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php). The user is storing a string without suffix that has a length of 6 (which is _12545 in this case).

```
echo.ren !CurrentFileName!%%~xf !RenameTo!%%~xf
```

I placed `echo` in front of `ren` so you can check before you actually rename it. `%%~xf` will return the file extension including .(dot) in front of it. In this case, the file extension is .pdf.

I hope this help a bit.

Comment: Thank you tiger,appriciate it